# Forcing a minimal font size on Android Chrome without any exceptions

Tags: chrome-for-android, 9.0-pie

Is it possible to **truly,** no ifs or buts, force a minimal font size on Android 9, Chrome 78?

Yes, it may break the layout, but that's another problem. I don't even get that far to get Chrome **consistently** apply text zoom and not to run in certain situations where it refuses to increase the font size.

An example website would be [this one](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Sample-diff-Input.html#Sample-diff-Input): with accessibility options you easily get the font size of the text outside of the beige boxes scaled, but the text inside of the beige boxes simply stays small.

Comment: Question is for Chrome ,  my answer of Firefox is not relevant, hence deleted